# Passing a string in where clause in Rails is always quoted

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause, quotes, composition

I'm trying to compose programmatically the `.where()` clause.

It looks like

```
Post.where("description ?", @composite)
```

Where `@composite` is a string which is constructed before. It may be something like `= 'ABCD'` or maybe `IS LIKE 'ABCD'` etc.

Problem is in the resulting SQL it's always single-quoted. For example:

```
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE (description 'IS LIKE "ABCD"')
```

Is there any way to "un-quote" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` and `IS LIKE` should not be part of the string you're passing in.

It's being single-quoted because that's precisely what the `?` does: SQL-safed quoting.

If you want to completely construct the SQL yourself then do so, e.g.,

```
Post.where("description #{@composite}")
```

You'll need to sanitize the string yourself, which is easy since presumably you're constructing the `=` or `IS LIKE` part with input.

Comment: That's the problem I tried to solve :) `Post.where("description #{@composite}")` is bad for SQL injection.

Comment: @valk But you can't do it the way you're trying to, the `?` explicitly safes the input value. You need to safe it yourself if you're going to not use the built-in mechanisms.

Comment: So the answer is, Rails doesn't know how to sanitize anything else than values for SQL :)

Comment: @valk Nothing else needs sanitizing.

Comment: Right, but would save time if there was sanitizing for whole chunks, no?

Comment: @valk It's the same process whether you or Rails does it. But how would Rails guess your intent?! You're passing an arbitrary string that happens to contain sql- expecting Rails to guess what you mean is asking too much.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Post.where("description #{@composite}")
```

Comment: then you have to change @composite creation

Comment: like try this:
search_string = "ABCD"
exact_match = false
Post.where("description #{exact_match ? '=' : 'LIKE'} ?", search_string)